# sed: replace multiline

Tags: regex, unity-game-engine, sed, zsh

I'm trying to do a multiline replace using **sed** on OSX (zsh).
My input file (Unity Asset file) looks like this:

```
...
displaySetting: 0
 applicationIdentifier:
  Android: com.appid.name
  Standalone: com.appid.name
  Tizen: com.appid.name
  iOS: com.appid.name
  tvOS: com.appid.name
buildNumber:
 iOS: 190
someOtherID: 190
moreIDsOverHere: 978987
...
```

I want to replace

```
buildNumber:
 iOS: 190
```

with

```
buildNumber:
 iOS: myBuildNumber
```

using the following command:

```
sed "N;s/^\\(.*buildNumber:.*.*$^.*iOS: \\)[0-9]*.*$/\\1myBuildNumber/;P;D" file.asset
```

This works except for *it also removes the last line*. I suspect this had something to do with my use of the pattern buffer, but I don't seem to be able to find a solution.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `$`, when used in the middle of the pattern, doesn't mean "newline."  Nor will `^` match the start of the second line when you have two lines in the pattern space.

Comment: You can modify to `'/buildNumber/{N;s/^\(.*buildNumber:.*iOS: \)[0-9]*.*$/\1myBuildNumber/;}'` and it would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use hold space here. Try this:

```
sed "/^[[:space:]]*buildNumber/{n;s/\(iOS: \)[0-9]*/\1myBuildNumber/;}" file
```

When `buildNumber` is found, `n` reads the next line and search for `iOS:` followed by numbers. If found, the pattern is replaced with `iOS`(using backreference) followed by `myBuildNumber`.

**Edit:**

To edit the file *in place* under OSX, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '' "/^[[:space:]]*buildNumber/{n;s/\(iOS: \)[0-9]*/\1myBuildNumber/;}" file
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. The file comes back unchanged. The last line is not removed so that's better, however it does not replace the build number. Note that I am on **OSX**, apparently there is quite some difference between GNU sed and OSX sed.

Comment: It's because of the spaces before `buildNumber` in your pastebin example. I updated my pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use awk for multiline record editing as:

```
awk '/buildNumber:/{p=NR} NR==p+1 && /iOS: [0-9]+/{sub(/iOS.*/, "iOS: myBuildNumber")} 1' file

dsplaySetting: 0
 applicationIdentifier:
  Android: com.appid.name
  Standalone: com.appid.name
  Tizen: com.appid.name
  iOS: com.appid.name
  tvOS: com.appid.name
buildNumber:
  iOS: myBuildNumber
someOtherID: 190
moreIDsOverHere: 978987
```

Comment: It did! The reason I used sed was that I wanted to change my file in-place using the -i flag. Unfortunately the OSX sed does not support in-place file edits so I had to pipe it to a temp file and move this temp file to the old filename.

Comment: It seems however the above commands removes the two spaces before "iOS". Do you know how to fix this? Unity doesn't like the format without the spaces.

Comment: This is the [output](https://pastebin.com/N7siBi7R). As you can see the two spaces before "iOS" are missing in the output.